# Room persistance library. Delete all

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components

How can I delete all entries on specific table using Room Persistence Library?
I need to drop table, but I cannot to find any information how to do this.

Only when database is migrating or to load all entries and delete them :)

Comment: As of Room 1.1.0 you can use `clearAllTables()` which "deletes all rows from all the tables that are registered to this database as entities()." I've included this as an answer below, but am reproducing here for visibility.

Comment: Because multiple people seem to be suggesting `clearAllTables()`, I can't help but point out that OP quite clearly says "How can I delete all entries on specific table".

Answer (score 627, accepted):

You can create a DAO method to do this.

```
@Dao 
interface MyDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM myTableName")
    public void nukeTable();
}
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't thought of that. I assumed that `@Query` was limited to things that return result sets (akin to `rawQuery()`). Very cool!

Comment: @yigit can I request that `@Delete` takes no parameter and delete all from the table? I'm trying to find Room's tracker to file that ...

Comment: it looks very misleading so no. + @Delete does not have a table annotation so we would not even know which table to clear.

Comment: Watch out! as for room alpha4 version, this technique will lead to a gradle build fail: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63608092

Comment: How about `Ids`? I did like this but Table Ids continue to increment. 
In real table drop Ids are also dropped to start from 0 again.

Comment: @yigit Is there a way to find out if the query ran successfully or if there was an error?

Comment: Deletion methods must either return void or return int (the number of deleted rows). @IoaneSharvadze

Comment: After clearAllTables(), how to create back all tables ?? Like in greenDao supports DAOMaster.dropAllTables() and Daomaster.createAllTables(). Something similar to this is supported in RoomDB ??

Comment: I get a "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time." Is suspend require for this function?

Answer (score 148):

As of Room `1.1.0` you can use [clearAllTables()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.html#clearAllTables()) which:

> Deletes all rows from all the tables that are registered to this database as entities().

Comment: Be careful: clearAllTables() is asynchronous and there is no way to tell when it completes.

Comment: @Alexey but could there be any trouble trying to save something after clearAllTables? As in, will it only attempt to insert AFTER clearing? Because I'm fine with that.

Comment: @FirstOne clearAllTables basically just starts a transaction on a new background thread. It deletes all data from tables and then commits that transaction. If you start your transaction later than clearAllTables starts its, youre fine. That being said, If you try to insert some data right after calling clearAllTable your insert might start before clearAllTable starts transaction and you'll loose all your data. If you need to insert new data right after calling clearAllTable, at least add some delay.

Comment: @Alexey Is there any way to use a callback method or similar to determine the state of the delete transaction?  In other words, if the delete transaction state is complete, then proceed with the insert data method.

Comment: @AJW No, as of now, there is still no way to tell when the operation is complete. If you really need this functionality, you might want to try something like `SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'` and then manually `DELETE FROM {TABLE}`. Haven't tested this though.

Comment: if you want to make sure you're waiting the appropriate amount of time, the best would be to set up a semaphore lock on your database object that is only released when an asynchronous process on a timer can confirm all tables are empty and decrements the semaphore. But to do this, all of your room operations have to respect the lock, which may not be trivial depending on your app's size.

Comment: After clearAllTables(), how to create back all tables ?? Like in greenDao supports DAOMaster.dropAllTables() and Daomaster.createAllTables(). Something similar to this is supported in RoomDB ??

Comment: Actually my use case  is to support multiple users login to my app.  When the user tries to change login number, i clear the old data and allow the user to login with new number. To achieve this, i need dropAllTables() and createAllTables in RoomDB.

Comment: `clearAllTables()` does NOT operates asynchronously, while it forces you to not call it from main thread.

Comment: It's throwing java.lang.IllegalStateException: A migration from 1 to 2 was required but not found.

Comment: @Dick, it's not the answer about deleting all rows from specific table.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to delete an entry from a table in Room, call this function:

```java
@Dao
public interface myDao{
    @Delete
    void delete(MyModel model);
}
```

If you want to delete the entire table, call this function:

```java
    @Query("DELETE FROM MyModel")
    void delete();
```

Here, `MyModel` is the table name.

Comment: i got this error after use your update code error: An abstract DAO method must be annotated with one and only one of the following annotations: Insert,Delete,Query,Update,RawQuery
    void delete();

Answer (score 16):

Use [clearAllTables()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase#clearAllTables()) with RXJava like below inorder to avoid `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.`

```
Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            getRoomDatabase().clearAllTables();
        }
    }).subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
            .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
            .subscribe(new Action() {
                @Override
                public void run() throws Exception {
                    Log.d(TAG, "--- clearAllTables(): run() ---");
                    getInteractor().setUserAsLoggedOut();
                    getMvpView().openLoginActivity();
                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
                    Log.d(TAG, "--- clearAllTables(): accept(Throwable throwable) ----");
                    Log.d(TAG, "throwable.getMessage(): "+throwable.getMessage());


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 10):

I had issues with delete all method when using **RxJava** to execute this task on background. This is how I finally solved it:

```
@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM User")
    fun deleteAll()
}
```

and

```
fun deleteAllUsers() {
    return Maybe.fromAction(userDao::deleteAll)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe ({
            d("database rows cleared: $it")
        }, {
            e(it)
        }).addTo(compositeDisposable)
}
```

Comment: When you are using Kotlin, you can just wrap it in `thread {}` instead of futzing with RxJava

Answer (score 9):

This is how we do it from a Fragment.

```
fun Fragment.emptyDatabase() {
    viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            Database.getInstance(requireActivity()).clearAllTables()
        }
    }
}
```

If you are emptying the database from an activity use this:

```
fun Activity.emptyDatabase() {
    // create a scope to access the database from a thread other than the main thread
    val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    scope.launch {
        SitukaDatabase.getInstance(this@emptyDatabase).clearAllTables()
    }
}
```

It could also be possible to call the `clearAllTables` method from the main thread. I haven't tried it out but I noticed that Android Studio does not recognize the call as a suspend function.

Answer (score 4):

Combining what [Dick Lucas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839500/dick-lucas) says and adding a reset autoincremental from other StackOverFlow posts, i think this can work:

```
fun clearAndResetAllTables(): Boolean {
    val db = db ?: return false

    // reset all auto-incrementalValues
    val query = SimpleSQLiteQuery("DELETE FROM sqlite_sequence")

    db.beginTransaction()
    return try {
        db.clearAllTables()
        db.query(query)
        db.setTransactionSuccessful()
        true
    } catch (e: Exception){
        false
    } finally {
        db.endTransaction()
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it’s worth, I’ve found it easiest to do this via context.deleteDatabase(“name”) and then simply reinstantiating and repopulating the database via the Room.databaseBuilder().addCallback upon first access.

Comment: What is sqlite_sequence?

Answer (score 2):

To make use of the Room without abuse of the `@Query` annotation first use `@Query` to select all rows and put them in a list, for example:

`@Query("SELECT * FROM your_class_table")`

```
List`<`your_class`>` load_all_your_class();
```

Put his list into the delete annotation, for example:

`@Delete`

```
void deleteAllOfYourTable(List`<`your_class`>` your_class_list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I have done it in Kotlin.

1. Inject room db in the activity using DI (Koin).

   ```
    private val appDB: AppDB by inject()
   ```
2. Then you can simply call clearAllTables()

```
private fun clearRoomDB() {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        appDB.clearAllTables()
        preferences.put(PreferenceConstants.IS_UPLOADCATEGORIES_SAVED_TO_DB, false)
        preferences.put(PreferenceConstants.IS_MEMBERHANDBOOK_SAVED_TO_DB, false)
    }
}
```