# Restricted API lint error when deleting table. Room Persistence

Tags: android, database, lint

So I am trying to delete all items in my Room Persistence table, which obviously led me to this :

```
@Dao 
interface MyDao {
    @Query("DELETE FROM myTableName")
    public void nukeTable();
}
```

[Stack overflow suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244508/room-persistance-library-delete-all/44249498#44249498)

However when running ./gradlew lint I am faced with a Restricted API failure as seen below.

[Dao_Impl.java](https://pastebin.com/utKp1s4S)

1.My Code

```
@Dao
public interface AlertDao {

    @Insert
    void insert(List<Alert> alert);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM alert")
    List<Alert> queryAll();

    @Query("DELETE FROM alert")
    void deleteTable();
}
```

2. My lint error

> Restricted API
> ../generated/source/apt/debug/com/app/test/storage/dao/AlertDao_Impl.java:>84: SharedSQLiteStatement.acquire can only be called from within the same >library group (groupId=android.arch.persistence.room)
> 81
> 82   @Override
> 83   public void deleteTable() {
> 84     final SupportSQLiteStatement _stmt = >__preparedStmtOfDeleteTable.acquire();
> 85     __db.beginTransaction();
> 86     try {
> 87       _stmt.executeUpdateDelete();
>
> ../generated/source/apt/debug/com/app/test/storage/dao/AlertDao_Impl.java:91: SharedSQLiteStatement.release can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=android.arch.persistence.room)
> 88       __db.setTransactionSuccessful();
> 89     } finally {
> 90       __db.endTransaction();
> 91       __preparedStmtOfDeleteTable.release(_stmt);
> 92     }
> 93   }
>
> ../generated/source/apt/debug/com/app/test/storage/dao/AlertDao_Impl.java:98: RoomSQLiteQuery can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=android.arch.persistence.room)
> 95   @Override
> 96   public List queryAll() {
> 97     final String _sql = "SELECT * FROM alert";
> 98     final RoomSQLiteQuery _statement = RoomSQLiteQuery.acquire(_sql, 0);
> 99     final Cursor _cursor = __db.query(_statement);
> 100     try {
> 101       final int _cursorIndexOfAutoGeneratedKey = _cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("autoGeneratedKey");
>
> ../generated/source/apt/debug/com/app/test/storage/dao/AlertDao_Impl.java:134: RoomSQLiteQuery.release can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=android.arch.persistence.room)
> 131       return _result;
> 132     } finally {
> 133       _cursor.close();
> 134       _statement.release();
> 135     }
> 136   }
> 137 }

Any help would be much appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found somewhat similar issue here [Android Architecture Component Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/63614424). As per the issue they might **ignore** generated code in **linting**.
Android Architecture Components still in ***alpha*** so they are working to fix it.

I used `deleteTable()` in my application and my DAO looks like

```
@Query("DELETE FROM tv_show")
void deleteTable();
```

And it worked for me without giving any lint errors.

```
D/TVShowViewModel: deleteTVShowTable: Delete
```

Make sure you are using **latest version** of *architecture components* and *gradle* to avoid any fixed bugs. Find latest release here [Android Architecture Components Releases](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/release-notes.html)

You can disable `RestrictedApi` as workaround for now in Android Studio Project gradle file

```
android {
  lintOptions {
    disable 'RestrictedApi'
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, Ill add the lintOption and that should assist my CI.