# How do I remove a database from an application?

Tags: android

When I run my application on my phone, I get the exception:

```
Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but 
forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the 
version number.
```

I know that I can use the method

```
fallbackToDestructiveMigration
```

But if I use it, then the callBack "onCreate" is never invoked (and I need it to be invoked).

The weird thing is that i get the message **even if I "clear data"** of the application (via de settings) and unistall the application. Apparently the database is never really removed from the phone, because I keep getting a versions conflict.

How can I really delete the database from the phone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply delete application or remove application data in your phone android system settings. Remember about:

```
<manifest ... >
...
<application android:allowBackup="false" ... >
    ...
</application>
```

or [Room persistance library. Delete all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44244508/room-persistance-library-delete-all)

Comment: I do this, but suprisingly it seems that the database is not really deleted, the phone remembers it and raises a version conflict even after uninstalling application. I don't understand...

Comment: You can check if your database file is still saved at your phone via ADB. There is also `fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` method which you can set in `Room.databaseBuilder()`

Edit: I am glad that I was able to help You :)