# Do Room queries happen asynchronously?

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, android-room

Are [Room Database](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/RoomDatabase) queries async? And if so, for lack of a better term, is something like this async/race condition safe?

```kotlin
fun insertThingAsync(thing: Thing) = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
  try {
    dao.deleteAllThings()
    dao.insertThing(thing)
  }
  catch (e: Throwable) {
    // Stuff
  }
}
```

In other words, is it possible, in this case, for the `dao` to attempt to insert the `thing` before `dao.deleteAllThings()` completes, and therefore have the chance of deleting the newly inserted `thing` as well?

If so, what are ways you all handle things like this to make sure you do not try to insert until the delete is complete?

I'm also wondering about the same use case with `roomDatabase.clearAllTables`, because of conversations [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49545016/10752877).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not async If they are plain `@Delete` and `@Insert` DAO methods, then they should be serialized naturally, as those methods are executed synchronously.

The only place where Room does asynchronous stuff is on `@Query` with a reactive return value (LiveData, Flowable, etc.).

There could be issues from concurrent modifications when starting multiple transactions/operations in different threads or from different Schedulers/Dispatchers.

In your case you have one coroutine in which they will run sequentially. So it is safe to think you will do delete first and then insert.

You can also create `Transaction` to execute multiple queries.

https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Transaction